# How to combine multiple timestamp into single value in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, workflow, metrics, promql

i have a metric like job_success_counter want i want to do is sum(job_success_counter)

in grafana i want to visualize it in table format and i just want the latest value , what i mean is total success jobs
but the way i get value in table is for each timestamp i get the value

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae5xd.png)
how to modify the query or any other way to fix this
query : sum(workflow_success_counter_total{workflow_type="PinoWorkflow"})

Comment: Switch type of query to Instant in collapsible many right under query itself.